# Skrollr refreshing issue

Tags: skrollr

I'm using skrollr in my site

It starts with an animation with fixed elements and the menu on bottom.
when it finished, the menu goes to absolute positioning, it is scrolled and when it reaches top, it get fixes again, but on top.

After the menu there is an absolute positioned section that goes over the animation.
The problem is when I slide down with jQuery some divs on this absolute positioning section, and after that, call refresh to fix the start of the animations.

When refresh is called, it fixed the animations that is inside the absolute positioned section, but it crashes the beginning animation because refresh change the start position of the animation...

The animation stay on its first state after refresh is called because it changes to start at a point the animation is no longer visible.

I wish I could refresh only the elements that are on the absolute positioned section

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var absolutePositioned = $('.refresh');
skrollr.init().refresh(absolutePosition);
```

or

```
var s = skrollr.init();
//... 
s.refresh($(".refresh"));
```